Flutter/Flutter.h file not found and other file-not-found errors from cached libraries in Xcode
I'm encountering multiple file-not-found errors in Xcode when trying to build my Flutter project for iOS. The primary issue seems to be with Flutter/Flutter.h not being found, followed by several other errors related to cached libraries such as sqflite, package_info_plus, and geocoding_ios.
This issue has occurred in a loop multiple times. I’ve tried several solutions, including:

Running flutter clean
Reinstalling Flutter dependencies with flutter pub get
Updating to the latest Flutter SDK
Removing and recreating the iOS build folder (ios/)
Verifying Xcode is updated and all necessary command-line tools are installed.

Here's a snippet of the errors:

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not
found
/Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/sqflite-2.3.0/ios/Classes/SqfliteImport.h:10:8
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not
found
/Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/package_info_plus-4.1.0/ios/Classes/FLTPackageInfoPlusPlugin.h:4:8
Error (Xcode):
/Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/geocoding_ios-2.3.0/ios/Classes/GeocodingHandler.h:
No such file or directory
Error (Xcode):
/Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/geocoding_ios-2.3.0/ios/Classes/Extensions/CLPlacemarkExtensions.h:
No such file or directory
Error (Xcode):
/Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/sqflite-2.3.0/ios/Classes/SqfliteDatabase.h:
No such file or directory
Error (Xcode):
/Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/sqflite-2.3.0/ios/Classes/SqflitePlugin.h:
No such file or directory
Error (Xcode):
/Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/sqflite-2.3.0/ios/Classes/SqfliteOperation.h:
No such file or directory
Error (Xcode):
/Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/sqflite-2.3.0/ios/Classes/SqfliteImport.h:
No such file or directory
Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
application on iPhone 15.

I expected these steps to resolve the build errors, but they keep reoccurring. How can I permanently fix this issue and prevent it from happening repeatedly?
Environment
Flutter SDK path: /Users/sdk/flutter/bin/flutter
Project path: /Users/vedic/vedicconnect_user/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
Flutter version: 3.24.3
Dart 3.5.3
What am I missing in the setup, or is there a specific step to ensure the cached libraries are properly integrated into the iOS build process?

Can you add flutter doctor to your post?
